# convert multiple incoming schemas to a single uniform schema in biztalk

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk

I have input files coming from several different source systems and they are all in different formats.

My aim is to convert them each into a uniform xml doc and dump them in a folder.

How can i do this in biztalk?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating an XSD for each single possible input type. Then I would create separate processes for each single input type and the implementation of each process would involve applying an XSLT transform to the input data. For this you would also need a separate XSLT for each input type so that the transformation converts the input type data to your expected output type.

Storing data in a folder is just as easy as selecting a file system adapter for the output port.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal Biztalk usage.

1. Create separate schema for all you incoming files (input files).
2. Create an output schema that contains all the information that the
   incoming schema includes. You can take the Canonical approach if you
   like and reference the incoming schema in an all included master
   schema. (see link for more information about this
   http://lingenfelder.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/create-a-canonical-schema-%E2%80%93-step-by-step/
   ).
3. Create maps that transform all the input files schemas to the output
   schema.
4. Create one receive port with different rec locations to each source
   system you got. Don’t forget to add the maps here.
5. Create one send port to the folder you like to store the files, and
   add a filter  that filters on BTS.ReceivePortName.